# how to prevent JpaRepository saveAndFlush generate delete sql request

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

JpaRepository saveAndFlush generate 2 sql request:
insert into invoice_line_group
delete from invoice_line_group

and the delete generate excecption:
 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: update or delete on table ....
Détail : Key (invoice_line_group_id)=(133109) is still referenced from table "invoice_line".

invoice_line_group , list of invoice_line

tables relation oneToMany :invoice_line_group 1----* invoice_line

Comment: FYI "JpaRepository" and "saveAndFlush" is nothing to do with the JPA API. It is "Spring Data JPA", a totally different API

Comment: yes i agree with u ! but why the delete is executed?

Comment: Depends on the code which is not included.